# Slurm: Is it possible to give or change pid of the submitted job via sbatch

Tags: slurm, sbatch

When we submit a job via `sbatch`, the pid to jobs given by incremental order. This order start from again from 1 based on my observation.

```
sbatch  -N1 run.sh
Submitted batch job 20
```

//Goal is to change submitted batch job's id, if possible.

**[Q1]** For example there is a running job under slurm. When we reboot the node, does the job continue running? and does its pid get updated or stay as it was before?

**[Q2]** Is it possible to give or change pid of the submitted job with a unique id that the cluster owner want to give?

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the node fails, the job is requeued - if this is permitted by the `JobRequeue` parameter in `slurm.conf`. It will get the same Job ID as the previously started run since this is the only identifier in the database for managing the jobs. (Users can override requeueing with the `--no-requeue` sbatch parameter.)

It's not possible to change Job ID's, no.

Comment: `JobRequeue=1` was commented on on my slurm.conf file. If I make it avaible, as I understand requeued will be done, but the job will start running from beginning and do not continue from where it left before the shut down.  If there will be `--no-requeue` after restart of the node, job will not run again right? @ciaron

Comment: With `JobRequeue=0` or `--no-requeue`, the job will not restart automatically - otherwise it will restart from the beginning.

If you want jobs to restart where they left off, you may want to look into checkpoint/restart with [BLCR](https://slurm.schedmd.com/checkpoint_blcr.html)